# How to serve media in Lift app?

Tags: lift

I am trying to migrate a simple django app to lift, but I can't seem to find a way to serve a simple image file!

Here is how it was in my django app:

```
<img src="/site_media/images/logos.jpg" />
```

Is there equivalent "site_media" directory where I can point lift (I am running jetty in eclipse right now)?

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In Boot.scala, you have to tell lift to let certain files be handled by the container (jetty or tomcat or whatever you're using).

```
LiftRules.passNotFoundToChain = true
LiftRules.liftRequest.append {
  case Req("my_stuff" :: _, _, _) => false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I just needed to put my images into the **src/webapp** folder in my project. So for the above path to work, the image should be in **src/webapp/site_media/images/logos.jpg**.